# Sending null terminated string to my C code through Python

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I am sending strings to my BPF C code and I am not sure if the strings passed in are null-terminated. If they are not, is there a way to make them null terminated? I am sending in my lines of code to BPF so I can count them manually using my stringCounter function but I keep hitting a forever loop sadly. Here is what my Python code looks like:

```
b = BPF(src_file="hello.c")

lookupTable = b["lookupTable"]
#add hello.csv to the lookupTable array
f = open("hello copy.csv","r")
contents = f.readlines()
for i in range(0,len(contents)):
    string = contents[i].encode('utf-8')
    lookupTable[ctypes.c_int(i)] = ctypes.create_string_buffer(string, len(string))
```

And here is the code I found for my null terminated string counter

```
int stringLength(char* txt)
{
    int i=0,count=0;
    
    while(txt[i++]!='\0'){
        count+=1;
    }
    
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: You only need one variable in that function: `int i = 0; for(; txt[i] != '\0'; ++i); return i;` Btw, why not use the standard `strlen` function?

Comment: I  am writing BPF code, so no support for strlen which requires string.h IIRC.

Comment: What is "BPF"?  Googling only found Berkley Packet Filter but not sure that is what you are talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctypes.create_string_buffer(string, len(string))` is not zero-terminated. But `ctypes.create_string_buffer(string)` is. It's easy to see that, since `ctypes.create_string_buffer(string)[-1]` is `b'\x00'`, whereas `ctypes.create_string_buffer(string, len(string))[-1]` is the last byte in `string`.

In other words, if you want a zero-terminated buffer, let `create_string_buffer` figure out the length. (It uses the actual length from the Python bytes object, so it doesn't get fooled by internal NUL bytes, if you were worried about that.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm unfamiliar with `BPF` but for `ctypes`, if your string isn't modified by the C code you don't need `create_string_buffer` as it is used to create mutable buffers, and Python Unicode and byte strings are both always passed nul-terminated `wchar_t*` or `char*`, respectively, to C code.  Assuming your function is in `test.dll` or `test.so`:

```py
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('./test')
dll.stringLength.argtypes = ct.c_char_p,
dll.stringLength.restype = ct.c_int

print(dll.stringLength('somestring'.encode()))  # If string is Unicode
print(dll.stringLength(b'someotherstring'))     # If already a byte string
```

Output:

```
10
15
```

Note this doesn't preclude having a nul in the string itself, but your count function will return a shorter value in that case:

```py
print(dll.stringLength(b'some\0string'))  # Output: 4
```

Your code could be probably be written as the following assuming there isn't some requirement that a `BPF` object have hard-coded `ctypes` types as indexes and values.

```py
with open("hello copy.csv") as file:
    for i,line in enumerate(file):
        lookupTable[i] = string.encode()
```